# Noise being created on Sensor after connecting Power Source to LEDs

Tags: arduino, led

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTnDs1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So I posted this issue on the arduino forums and haven't had much luck getting any visuals on it. I have an arduino and shield of which I've configured to work on a 12volt dc car battery. However, I am running into issues with the accelerometer giving me fluctuating readings at rest when I add power to the LEDs.

For example, no power connected to leds, and the arduino is connected to the computer, sensor values fluctuate +- 1 of the normal at rest value. However, as soon as the power is added to the buck sensor (To drop the 12 volts down to 5.5 for the LEDs) my values immediately fluctuate +-5 of this old value. The only places where the arduino and LEDs connect is through my shield at the COM port (a digital output on arduino) and a ground wire that grounds directly to the arduino. The power wire is a separate entity (although in the final configuration they both will be powered by a car battery).

In this instance however arduino is powered by laptop and LEDs through a battery. With the + lead of the battery going straight to the positive terminal of the buck converter. Any idea what gives?

Comment: Could you please provide some schematics?

Comment: At current time no as I am away from the laptop that has the Eagle Cad Files on it. I will update this post as soon as I am around that laptop. Would a hand draw picture help at the moment?

Comment: And most important, the unit of measure you are speaking about... +- 1 m/s2? +- 1 digits (if so, what is the full scale range)? +- 1 apples or bananas?

Comment: @Dragono any visual aid is better than just text descriptions :)

Comment: Ok visual aid is up. And my units are simple ADC values.

Comment: Please use the built in circuit editor, from your tiny photo I can not read anything. Also edit in the proper units etc. into your questions, the question should be understandable without having to dig through comments. Also my guess is that you are just missing decoupling caps.

Comment: How is the -ve connection made between the LED controller and the micro? Your diagram shows a common -ve from both going to the battery. Have you tried different arrangement e.g. a direct connection between the micro -ve and LED controller -ve running with the comms signal? You mention a connection through a shield, is that shown on the diagram? Does changing the physical proximity of the 2 boards affect the amount of noise?

Comment: Is it really necessary to use 5.5 V on the leds? If it is, is it really necessary to use a Buck converter? Switching converters add a lot of noise. Whenever you can provide the actual Eagle circuit you will have a precise answer, but for now these are just hypothesis.

Comment: PlasmaHH I just found out that there was a built in feature to add circuits. Yes 5.5 volts is necessary for these LEDs as per the manufacturers specs.

Comment: User158 the Leds get there power from the battery through the vcc ports. But they are told when to light up through the Comm port.

Comment: Ok schematic uploaded. The arduino in this instance is powered by laptop through USB not shown. Leds cannot be powered directly through arduino as that 5volt can only put out about 250Ma.

Comment: Just saw that I accidentally connected my 12 volt to the ground coming from the arduino. That should be connected to the ground of the battery and the buck converter.

Comment: @Dragono fixed Schematic. What kind of LEDs? WS2 something something? And the Accelerometer, is it a module? Part number/link/datasheet please. Do you have any capacitors laying around?

Comment: Yes and yes I have a few ceramic caps

Comment: Try adding a 100µF to 1000µF electrolytic cap across the LED V+ and Gnd, and add a 0.1µF and/or 1µF across the Accelerometer V+ and Gnd.

Comment: I was thinking, maybe to add some caps across the VCC and ground of the sensor but I don't think I have any capacitors big enough to keep up with the possible 1amp draw of the LEDs. I'll be honest if it's not already apparent my knowledge of how capacitors work is somewhat limited.

Comment: Oh I see I answered your question. I will have to venture out into the world and find 100uf or 1000 UF caps.

Comment: @Dragono the sensor only needs a small ceramic or mylar cap, 0.1 or 1µF. (marked 104 and 105,respectfully). The bigger cap is for the leds, and can be any value between 100 to 1000 µF. 470µF for example.

Comment: Looks like a run to radio shack is in order. They disappoint many a times though. In any case I will report back. Also should this capacitor go before or after the buck sensor assuming before means closer to the battery source side in the schematic

Comment: @Dragono at the led's connection. A cap should always go as close to the device in question as possible. Same with the smaller ones for the ADXL, as close to the module as you can. And RS should have a 20 pk of mixed electrolytic capacitors (Sku 272-0802) for 5 bucks. Better than the single capacitor at 1.50.

Comment: @Passerby  I was a bit impatient and didn't read this before buying it. In any case the cap on the LEDs reduces the output noise but there is still residuals. I tried to cap the vcc and ground on the accelerometer with a ceramic cap and my ADC values immediately drop to zero. And even after removing the cap they remained at 0. I don't think the cap had any charge from anything before hand in any case I make assemble a new board. But in between time I'm going to use a bread board to test this. Will report back.

Comment: @Passerby Tested on bread board and the raw reading is +-1 everytime. However, in doing my deductive reasoning I found that the Buck converter I use with the bread board and the converter soldered onto the board are the issue. My stand alone converter is the only different thing used even tried grounding them in different ways to try to simulate my proto board. Any reason why one is helping my sensor put out more stable reading than the other? Also tried decoupling caps on both sides of the noisy buck with no real difference and a smaller cap on the accelerometer. I was still seeing noise +-4

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/RioRand-LM2596-Converter-1-23V-30V-1Pcs-LM2596/dp/B008BHAOQO  this is the noisy one   http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00JUFJ1GA?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s02 this is the good one

Comment: Most likey, crappy regulation. Caps may be bad. Or the ic and or caps are fake. I doubt that's a legit linear semiconductor part. Sometimes these modules are crap shots